# Is there any function to display data as html content, i'm saving the data as html formats

Tags: javascript, html, django, summernote

I used summernote in my web page and getting the result from it has html tag. But when i tried to display as its not showing.

I tried to use Parse data as HTML still not use.

test.html

```
 <form action="{% url 'polls:gotopage' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.content|safe }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <h3>Testing</h3>
        <p>{{ page.content }}</p>   
        <div id="summernote"><p>{{ page.content }}</p></div>
  </form>
 <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote();
});

  </script>
```

I'm getting the data as raw data. No html style or changes. i want to make its look like html content.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Mustache documentation](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html):

> All variables are HTML escaped by default. If you want to return
>   unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{ content }}}.

So your test.html will look something like this:

```
     <form action="{% url 'polls:gotopage' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.content|safe }}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <h3>Testing</h3>
            <p>{{{ page.content }}}</p>   
            <div id="summernote"><p>{{{ page.content }}}</p></div>
      </form>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote();
    });
  </script>
```